# CSS3 transition only happens once

Tags: css, transition

I am trying to transition a background-color, but it is only happening once on [www.kent.co.nf](http://www.kent.co.nf) social media icons. What is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a terrible question. Try to better learn [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry guys that was my first post. I'll try to remember all that but it looks like I got the answer anyway. Thanks for keeping the place running!

Comment: Woo! It's working brilliantly now with quite a few less lines of code ;)  www.kent.co.nf  
I even added the same effect to standard links ;) Does it remind anyone else of Half Life? haha... I may change the colours per link, just because I can... I'd like to exploit the versatility of doing it without image files- 'the old way'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added permanent style property `background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);` after mouseover on the element.
You should remove this

It opposes for the style

```
IMG.c_icon:hover {
    background-color: #ff7700;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review my code on a badly posted question, and that will be the problem, I'll fix it later. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Woo! It's working brilliantly now with quite a few less lines of code ;) www.kent.co.nf I even added the same effect to standard links ;) Does it remind anyone else of Half Life? haha... I may change the colours per link, just because I can... I'd like to exploit the versatility of doing it without image files- 'the old way'. –

Answer (score 0):

in your code.you not mention on `onmouseout` .on mouse hover it will add class.but on mouse out it not deleting any class.
can you add this listener to that element.it will work.

intand of using **js** to achieve this function.you

```css
div{
transition:all 1s linear;
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
div:hover{

  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

can achieve this functionality using **css**.like using **:hover**

```
img{trasitiion :all 0.5s,background-color:red}
img:hover(background-color:blue)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm just getting used to 'dynamic' CSS. I think I'll need to use js to switch between classes to achieve the final desired transition, I only want fade out not fade in.